# Duplicate Mathematica functionality in Mathematica clone or lisp

Tags: replacement, variable

What is the easiest way to accomplish the following in a Mathematica clone or in any version of Lisp?  Also it doesn't appear in any lisps [have a similar replace function](http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp).

```
Replace[arg, f[{x_, "[", y__, "]"}] :> x[y]]
```

You are welcome to vote to close the same question has been asked [at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594260/duplicate-mathematica-functionality-in-mathematica-clone-or-lisp).  I'm not going to delete it because I think it is beneficial for search.

Comment: I don't believe questions about Lisp are on-topic here. Why do you feel your question is on-topic?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Mathematica clones is own topic(I just included lisp for completion).  Do you think I should post it over at stackoverflow then.  I'm just afraid it won't get the right attention.

Comment: @William Are you asking for a solution using Mathics, http://www.mathics.org ?

Comment: You may want to look at the `replace` function [here](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/patterns/recursion.html), although it only replaces specific symbols, not patterns. Richard Fateman has implemented a toy version of Mathematica evaluator in Lisp (not sure how complete that implementation is, I unfortunately had no chance to look into it), so perhaps that is as close as it gets to what you are interested in.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Mathics is fine I am just looking for patterns support.

Comment: stackoverflow with both `mathematica` and `lisp` tags. Give some usage examples.

Comment: @William "Mathics is fine[...]" - I installed mathics but I was not able to run it. "[...] I am just looking for patterns support." -- I have a solution in mind that uses Functional Parsers (which are available in many languages, like, Scala, C#). My idea was to show how to create a parser for your problem using this package: https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m  . (If you are  interested I will do that.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I would love an attempt in any language really.  I'm stumped.  Nothing seems anywhere near as simple as M version.

Comment: @William Clojure has a limited [form of destructuring](https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844) , which is somewhat similar to patterns, although much less general. However, it works pretty well still, for things that are needed in practice, such as bindings for passed arguments or their parts for functions, and the like.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin +1 for the example, but it doesn't seem to cover replacement rules.  If all you are doing is selecting then using indexes(like I sometimes) isn't to bad.  It just when you get into replacement rules.  It seems like there should be an easy way to do such, but I don't see it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because emulating _Mathematica_ functionality in other programming languages does not fall into the purview of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution using *Mathematica* and the package [FunctionalParsers.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) available at GitHub. This solution might not look very pretty. And used infix notation in order to get shorter code.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/FunctionalParsers.m"]

varNameParser = 
  ParseApply[StringJoin, 
   ParseMany1[
    ParsePredicate[
     StringLength[#] > 0 && StringMatchQ[#, WordCharacter] &]]];

varSequenceParser = ParseListOf[varNameParser, ParseSymbol[","]];

fArgsParser = ParseApply[#[[1]] <> "[" <> Riffle[#[[2]], ","]
     <> "]" &, (varNameParser \[LeftTriangle] 
      ParseSymbol[","])\[CircleTimes]ParseBracketed[
     ParseSymbol[","] \[RightTriangle] (varSequenceParser)]];

fParser = 
  ParseSymbol["f"] \[RightTriangle] 
   ParseBracketed[ParseCurlyBracketed[fArgsParser]];

fsListParser = 
  ParseCurlyBracketed[ParseListOf[fParser, ParseSymbol[","]]];
```

The result from applying the last parser, `fsListParser`, to:

```
argStr = "{f[{m,[,1,2,3,]}],f[{x,[,y,]}],f[{c,[,a,b,]}]}"
```

is this:

```
{{{}, {"m[1,2,3,]", "x[y,]", "c[a,b,]"}}}
```

I am not sure how satisfying this final result is. I am mostly trying to illustrate the use of Functional Parsers (or [parser combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator)) for this kind of problem. In short, the parsing recognizes the pattern and the pattern is being acted upon using ParseApply.

Let us look at what the parsers do in turn.

1. varNameParser -- parsing a sequence of letters and numbers as an entity.

   In[243]:= varNameParser[{"a", "b"}]

   Out[243]= {{{}, "ab"}}
2. varSequenceParser -- parsing a list of entities.

   Here we get several alternatives of successful parsing. The first one is the one we want.

   In[274]:= varSequenceParser[Characters["ab,1232,x"]]

   Out[274]= {{{}, {"ab", "1232", "x"}}, {{",", "1", "2", "3", "2", ",", 
      "x"}, {"ab"}}, {{"a", "b", ",", "1", "2", "3", "2", ",", "x"}, {}}}
3. fArgsParser -- parses the internal arguments of f.

   This parser also applies a function to the parsed result using ParseApply. (The comma after "m" shows that my implementation of ParseListOf has a bug.)

   In[275]:= fArgsParser[Characters["x,[,y,m,]"]]

   Out[275]= {{{}, "x[y,m,]"}}
4. fParser -- parse an instance of f[__] .

   In[234]:= fParser[Characters["f[{x,[,y,]}]"]]

   Out[234]= {{{}, "x[y,]"}}
5. fsListParser -- parse a list of f terms.

   In[305]:= fsListParser[Characters[argStr]]

   Out[305]= {{{}, {"m[1,2,3,]", "x[y,]", "c[a,b,]"}}}
6. The output of fsListParser in 5 is a list of strings not a string. If we want a string for the output we can modify fsListParser with ParseApply:

   fsListParser =
     ParseCurlyBracketed[
      ParseApply[
       "{" <> StringJoin @@ Riffle[#, ","] <> "}" &,
       ParseListOf[fParser, ParseSymbol[","]]]];

   Now we obtain a string:

   In[293]:= fsListParser[Characters[argStr]]

   Out[293]= {{{}, "{m[1,2,3,],x[y,],c[a,b,]}"}}

This might seem quite messy. I am not sure is this solution the easiest, but it is quite universal. I find this technique quite powerful.

The package [FunctionalParsers.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) can generate parsers from BNF specifications. I opted of writing the parsers directly in order to better illustrate the technique. The functional parsers can be relatively easily implemented in any functional language. (I have made implementations in Mathematica, R, and Lua.) Scala has functional parsers included in it. There are packages for C# and Java.

This blog post of mine has explanations and references on functional parsers application: [Natural language processing with functional parsers](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/natural-language-processing-with-functional-parsers/) . This presentation has technical details: [Functional parsers for an integration requests language](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/Functional%20parsers%20for%20an%20integration%20requests%20language%20grammar.pdf) .

Comment: Give me a second to read it all.  But it appears you have just proposed using a Package. I'm trying to avoid using Mathematica.

Comment: @William I thought I can run that package in Mathics. (Now I don't think so.) Nevertheless, you can use this solution in Scala and Haskel. (They have monadic parsers.) I am sure there are packages for monadic parsers in Lisp -- see https://github.com/drewc/smug .

Comment: If you know how to do it in lisp I will happily accept the answer.  I gave an upvote but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @William Yeah, I am interested to do a Lisp solution. I plan to make one later this week. I provided a Mathematica solution because of the comments to your question, and because I thought it will work with Mathics. Thanks for the up-vote!